# XSLT 2.0: Tokenize does not work on period character (full stop / dot)

Tags: xslt, tokenize

XSLT's tokenize function is not working as I expected when tokenizing on a period character '.'

--

Here is an example of what happens when I tokenize over a comma character:

XML file:

```
<value>a,b,c</value>
```

XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <firsttoken><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(/value,',')[1]" /></firsttoken>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<firsttoken>a</firsttoken>
```

--

Here is the same example but tokenizing over a period character:

XML file:

```
<value>a.b.c</value>
```

XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <firsttoken><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(/value,'.')[1]" /></firsttoken>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<firsttoken/>
```

--

I can't work out why it works for commas but not for period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` is a special character both in XSLT (shorthand for the context node) and in a regular expression (any alphanumerical character).

If you'd like to match a literal "." you need to escape it with a backslash in front.

> I can't work out why it works for commas but not for period.

The tokenization does work for periods. It is just that `.` is not interpreted as a period in the first place.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <firsttoken><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(/value,'\.')[1]" /></firsttoken>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><firsttoken>a</firsttoken>
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks your help. I was thinking that the tokenize function tokenized on a literal string rather than a pattern.

Comment: +1.  So in the original example from @CraigJohnstone the `tokenize` function _is_ in fact working as designed - you've given a separator regex of `.` which matches any single character, so tokenize will treat every character as a separator and return a sequence of empty strings, from which you're selecting the first.